# Twilio Client Python not Working in IOS Browser

Tags: javascript, python, ios, flask, twilio

I have created a simple twilio client application to make phone calls from Web Browser to phones. I used a sample Flask app to  generate a secure Capability Token and used `twilio.min.js` library to handle calls from my HTML.
The functionality works fine in Computer Browsers and Android Phone Browsers, but fails in IOS browsers(checked both in Safari and Chrome). In android the page asks for permission to use mic and headphone but in IOS it doesnot even as for that. Is there anything that I am missing here? It would be really helpful if someone can throw some light into this.
The doc I referred to was : [Twilio Hello Monkey Client](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/python/client/hello-monkey)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio Client uses WebRTC and falls back to Flash in order to make web browsers into phones. Unfortunately Safari on iOS supports neither WebRTC nor Flash so Twilio Client cannot work within any browser on iOS.

It is possible to build an [iOS application to use Twilio Client](https://www.twilio.com/docs/client/ios) just not a web application.

Comment: Thanks @philnash , wasted a lot of time on this.

Comment: It would be good if the Twilio Javascript Client would call the Twilio.Device.error() callback on IOS in this case.  This would allow other fallback code to work normally.  As it now stands, call Twilio.Device.connect() fails silently and no callback is called.